# How to print JSON objects correctly after successful JSONP request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

How to correctly parse/print JSON "scores" objects into demo div (I need just away, home and score data of each)?

My JSON query look like this (code below is also working)

```
{ "query": { "count": 18, "created": "2016-09-07T06:10:58Z", "lang": "fi", "results": { "json": [ { "scores": { "away": "ESBJERG ENERGY", "home": "EV ZUG", "match_type": "fin", "status": "fin", "matchId": "1311357", "score": "3-2", "image": "EUROPE (IIHF)" } }, { "scores": { "away": "HC DAVOS", "home": "ROUEN", "match_type": "fin", "status": "fin", "matchId": "1311356", "score": "2-3", "image": "EUROPE (IIHF)"}}]}}}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="results"></div>

  <div id="resultsshouldbelikethis">
   EV ZUG - ESBJERG ENERGY (3-2)<br>
   ROUEN - HC DAVOS (2-3)<br>
   ...and so on
 </div>

  <script>
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20scores%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3a%2f%2fmobile.xscores.com%2fm_livescore%3fsport%3d4%26match_type%3dlive%26match_date%3d2016-09-06%26startPos%3d0%26endPos%3d5000%22%20limit%2050&format=json",
      type: "GET",
      timeout: 3000,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(parsa) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =
          parsa.query.scores;
        console.log(parsa);
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Console log works well but how to print results nicely into a div? "parsa.query.scores;" just results undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop each data one-by-one and add them into div.

Try this:

```js
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20scores%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3a%2f%2fmobile.xscores.com%2fm_livescore%3fsport%3d4%26match_type%3dlive%26match_date%3d2016-09-06%26startPos%3d0%26endPos%3d5000%22%20limit%2050&format=json"
        , type: "GET"
        , timeout: 3000
        , dataType: "jsonp"
        , success: function (parsa) {
            var strHtml = '';

            $.each(parsa.query.results.json, function (key, value) {
                strHtml += value.scores.home + ' - ' + value.scores.away;
                strHtml += '(' + value.scores.score + ')<br />';
            });

            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = strHtml;
        }
    });
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @sukkis: glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery  2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="results"></div>

  <div id="resultsshouldbelikethis">
   EV ZUG - ESBJERG ENERGY (3-2)<br>
   ROUEN - HC DAVOS (2-3)<br>
   ...and so on
 </div>

  <script>
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20scores%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3a%2f%2fmobile.xscores.com%2fm_livescore%3fsport%3d4%26match_type%3dlive%26match_date%3d2016-09-06%26startPos%3d0%26endPos%3d5000%22%20limit%2050&format=json",
      type: "GET",
      timeout: 3000,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(parsa) {
       var news = document.getElementsById("results");
var items =  parsa.query.scores;
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var p= document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = items[i].away;
    news.appendChild(p);
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = items[i].home;
    news.appendChild(p);
var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = items[i].score;
    news.appendChild(p);

}
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't parsing the JSON properly. Here is an example which shows the first score. You have to iterate the results to show each score.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="results"></div>

  <div id="resultsshouldbelikethis">
   EV ZUG - ESBJERG ENERGY (3-2)<br>
   ROUEN - HC DAVOS (2-3)<br>
   ...and so on
 </div>

  <script>
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20scores%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3a%2f%2fmobile.xscores.com%2fm_livescore%3fsport%3d4%26match_type%3dlive%26match_date%3d2016-09-06%26startPos%3d0%26endPos%3d5000%22%20limit%2050&format=json",
      type: "GET",
      timeout: 3000,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(parsa) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =
          parsa.query.results.json[0].scores.score;
        console.log(parsa);
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Nice! This made my day. I'll accept this solution after few minutes once I could.

Comment: Cool. Happy to help :)